# Parsing a a text file delimited by a pipeline

Tags: android

I'm a new be in android development, just need to know if there's any way you can parse a text file, delimited by a pipeline?

Thanks,

Comment: Please explain the question?Elaborate on text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You want to read the content of a text file and want the whole data in chunks of String seperated based on pipeline? IF i am right following code would be helpful:

```
public class FileReader {
      private String fileType;
      FileReader (String targetFilePath){
        File file = new File(targetFilePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Log.e("",targetFilePath + " does not exist.");
        } else if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
            Log.e("",file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
        } else {
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                fileBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
                //Use FileBufferedInputStream just for supporting mark()/reset() while reading 
                // reading file extension ex. java or xml or txt
                this.fileType = targetFilePath.substring(
                        targetFilePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1,
                        targetFilePath.length());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("",""+e.printStackTrace());
            }
        }
      }


/*
This method will return a arraylist of Strings which are seperated by '|' in given  txt file 
and null otherwise like if file was not text,blank.etc
*/
    public ArrayList<String> read(){ 
        if(fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")){
        char currentChar;
        ArrayList<String> myStringsList ;
        while (fileBufferedInputStream.available() > 0) {
               StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               while ((currentChar = (char) fileBufferedInputStream.read()) == '|') {
                   stringBuilder.append(current);
               }
               if(null == myStringsList){
                 myStringsList = new ArrayList<String>();
               }  
               myStrings.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }    
        }
        fileBufferedInputStream.close();
        return myStringsList ;
}


 }
```

Now Call Above code as follows:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Path to your text file");
ArrayList<String> stringsSeperatedByPipeDelimeters = fileReader.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply read your file to a String and split the String using pipeline or any other delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

You Also Can Do Something Like This:

```
private String[] getPipedChunks(String targetFilePath){
           File file = new File(targetFilePath);
           try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           }
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  Log.e("",""+e.printStackTrace());
           }
           StringBuilder sb;
           while(fileInputStream.available() > 0) {

       if(null== sb)  sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append((char)fileInputStream.read());
       }
       String stringArray [];
       if(null!=sb){
            stringArray = sb.toString.split('|');
            // This is your String Array.


       }
       try {
          fileInputStream.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.e("",""+e.printStackTrace());
       }
           return stringArray;
}
```